# how i can modify the search option on my website so that mistyped words too give some suggestion

Tags: elasticsearch, search

using mysql "like" function for the current search and want to modify it using jaro-winkler. 
what would be the best method to implement it. 
a php code, a js code or a mysql function?

the column to be searched contains around 1M rows!!

Comment: If you’re using elasticsearch, use fuzzy queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`jaro-winkler` function compares two string and returns float value depending on the match between two strings (you can change return type). if both string equal then 1 else less than 1 value.

So take advantage of `jaro-winkler` and compare mistype word with your valid values.

You need to store all the valid values (which are used for search using like expression) in some table.

```
SELECT t.colname AS name,MAX(jaro_winkler_similarity('$mistypeword',t.colname )) AS jvalue FROM tablename AS t;
```

This query gives you the maximum possible correct value for mistyped word.

As you said you have 1 million rows then, above query might be taken to much time to give you a response.

So just take values from query then your php find maximum possible valid value.

```
$sql = "SELECT t.colname AS name,jaro_winkler_similarity('$mistypeword',t.colname ) AS jvalue FROM tablename AS t";
$resultset = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("database error:". mysqli_error($conn));
$value = 0;

while( $rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultset) ) {
    $new_val = $rows['jvalue'];
    if($value < $new_val ){
        $value = $new_val;
        $search_name = $rows['name'];
    }
}
```

`$search_name` is the maximum possible correct word for mistype word.you can use this value to do your remaining operation.

*Note: You can also display a string on the browser like you are showing the result (correct word) instead of the mistyped word.*